# (Android) How can i use a listView as buttons?

Tags: android, listview, button, android-fragments, viewflipper

I have the following code: and a list appears on my fragment. How can i use the list items as buttons so when i click on them to change the page from the ViewFlipper?
I tried using a variable (changepage) witch is initialised with -1. and to get the position of the adapter into it. so that on click to check how much it is, and to change the displaychildren function of the ViewFlipper

```
package com.weinco.fragments;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

import com.weinco.R;


public class VinocardFragment extends Fragment {
int mNum;
private ListView menuItemList;
private ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;
public static String text;
public static ViewFlipper VF;
public static ListView listViewVino;
public static final ArrayList<String> ListviewContent = new ArrayList<String>();
public static int changepage=-1;

/**
 * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num" as an
 * argument.
 */
static VinocardFragment newInstance(int num) {
    VinocardFragment f = new VinocardFragment();

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("num", num);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}

// ListView

public static class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context) {

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return ListviewContent.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ListContent holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewinflate, null);

            holder = new ListContent();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.TextView01);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ListContent) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(ListviewContent.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {
        if (position==0){
            changepage=0;
        }
    }

    class ListContent {
        TextView text;

    }
}

/**
 * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;

}

/**
 * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its instance number.
 */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vinocard, container, false);
    VF = (ViewFlipper) v.findViewById(R.id.viewFlipperVino);

    OnClickListener anmeldenListener;
    OnClickListener zuruckListener;
    OnClickListener zuruckListener2;

    // Variables
    ImageButton anmeldenB = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.anmelden);
    ImageButton backB = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.backVinoNr);
    ImageButton backB2 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.backVinomenu);
    menuItemList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listViewVino);
    EditText vE = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.vinonr);
    text = vE.getText().toString();
    getMenuItems();




    // Onclick Listeners for buttons
    anmeldenListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            VF.showNext();

            menuItemList.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

        }

    };

    if (changepage==0){
        VF.showNext();

    }


    zuruckListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    };
    zuruckListener2 = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            VF.showPrevious();
        }
    };

    //Get Item ID's to pages




    anmeldenB.setOnClickListener(anmeldenListener);
    backB.setOnClickListener(zuruckListener);
    backB2.setOnClickListener(zuruckListener2);
    return v;
}

private void getMenuItems() {
     ListviewContent.add("Exklusivangebote");
     ListviewContent.add("Gutschein schneken");
     ListviewContent.add("Kundendaten");
     ListviewContent.add("Meine Gutscheine");
     ListviewContent.add("Jahresbonus");
     listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity());

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it:

menuItemList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> menuItemList, View v, int position,
             long id) {
           changepageothers=position;
            if (changepageothers==0){              
             VF.showNext();
             changepageothers=-1;
            }
            if (changepageothers==1){
             VF.showPrevious();
             changepageothers=-1;
            }

           }
          });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extend `ListFragment` as opposed to `Fragment` and implement `onListItemClick()`. From there, you can get the id of the `ListView` item clicked and do whatever you will with it.

To implement `onListItemClick()`,

1. Right-click your codespace.
2. Mouse-over "Source"
3. Click "Override/Implement Methods"
4. Find and check `onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)`
5. Click "OK" to implement checked methods.

Find `onListItemClick` in your code and you should see:

```
public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
   // l - ListView that was clicked
   // v - View that was clicked within ListView l
   // position - Position of View v within ListView l
   // id - row id of item that was clicked
}
```

Comment: P.S. I'm not sure how `Fragments` work, but you might want to remove the `import com.weinco.R` statement as importing any R file is unnecessary and could possibly mess up your build.

Comment: how do i get the id of the ListView item? sorry but im new to list views, and im learning:p

Comment: Updated answer, give it a look-see.

Comment: It doesnt let me change to ListFragment: Logcat Says:

07-18 16:31:46.242: E/AndroidRuntime(7535): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 16:31:46.242: E/AndroidRuntime(7535): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.weinco/com.weinco.activity.WeinCoTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-18 16:31:46.242: E/AndroidRuntime(7535):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

Comment: Judging from the LogCat, you should change your `ListView` id to "android.R.id.list".

Comment: Actually it should be `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: doesn't work with them like that, and also i tried  android:id="@+id/list" and still nothing